# Pepper android app never started function onRobotFocusGained() on a real pepper

Tags: android, kotlin, pepper

I have a problem with some simple kotlin code on a pepper robot. I followed the "get started" tutorial from softbanks (https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/hello_human_tutorial.html) and it works fine, except to start the function onRobotFocusGained. I have implemented some logs to see, that the program starts the functions "onCreate", "onStart" and "onResume" but never the "onRobotFocusGained". If I start the code from the tutorial on GitHub (https://github.com/aldebaran/qisdk-tutorials), it works fine. But this program is too heavy for any complete beginners.
My goal is to implement a minimal example for my colleagues to start with programming on pepper.

So, how pepper starts the function "onRobotFocusGained" (https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch2_principles/focus_lifecycle.html#focus-lifecycle)?

Here is my short program for pepper to say once "hello humans" if i start the program but pepper never says it.

```
package com.example.hello_pepper_2

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.com.aldebaran.qi.sdk.QiContext
import android.com.aldebaran.qi.sdk.QiSDK
import android.com.aldebaran.qi.sdk.RobotLifecycleCallbacks
import android.com.aldebaran.qi.sdk.`object`.conversation.Say
import android.com.aldebaran.qi.sdk.builder.SayBuilder
import android.com.aldebaran.qi.sdk.design.activity.RobotActivity

class MainActivity : RobotActivity(), RobotLifecycleCallbacks {

    var robotContext: QiContext? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Register the RobotLifecycleCallbacks to this Activity.
        QiSDK.register(this, this)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Log.e("MSG", "onCreate")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        Log.e("MSG", "onStart")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        Log.e("MSG", "onResume")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")
    }

    override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()

        Log.e("MSG", "onRestart")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

        Log.e("MSG", "onPause")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        Log.e("MSG", "onStop")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        // Unregister the RobotLifecycleCallbacks for this Activity.
        QiSDK.unregister(this, this)
        super.onDestroy()

        robotContext = null

        Log.e("MSG", "onDestroy")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")
    }

    override fun onRobotFocusGained(qiContext: QiContext) {
        // The robot focus is gained.

        robotContext = qiContext

        saySomething("Hello Humans")

        Log.e("MSG", "onRobotFocusGained")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")
    }

    override fun onRobotFocusLost() {
        // The robot focus is lost.

        Log.e("MSG", "onRobotFocusLost")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")
    }

    override fun onRobotFocusRefused(reason: String) {
        // The robot focus is refused.

        Log.e("MSG", "onRobotFocusRefused")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")
    }

    fun saySomething(phrase: String) {
        Log.e("MSG", "saySomething")
        Log.e("Context", "robot.Context.toString()")

        val say: Say = SayBuilder
            .with(robotContext)
            .withText(phrase)
            .build()

        say.run()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your robot awake, i.e. not in the rest position?

Comment: Yes, the robot is awake and look around. The tutorial works fine but my code don't start the robot lifecycle, only the android lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue about the RobotService app, that sometimes fails to make the Android apps communicate with the robot. Make sure to update it to the latest version via the Command Center.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have installed this app via the command center and test some new code. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

There was nothing in your code that seems wrong to me, but as a debugging-approach, you may try to copy-paste the official tutorial file to make sure your robot isn't faulty. If the official version works; look closely at the differences

https://github.com/aldebaran/qisdk-tutorials/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/softbankrobotics/qisdktutorials/ui/tutorials/gettingstarted/HelloHumanTutorialActivity.kt